# Lighthouse: Speed Index - Invalid score for speed-index: NaN

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, lighthouse

Does anyone know what this error even means?  It is non-descript does not really lend itself to a debugging path.  This occurs when testing page speed in google Lighthouse.

[image]

Comment: does it work on the mobile version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facing the same issue and raised to the lighthouse Github repo.

Refer: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11173

They are able to reproduce it and will be fixing this soon as part of this ticket: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11154

[image]

Comment: is it fixed? or is it still an issue?

Comment: I don't think so, but they have marked the issue as closed. Maybe it's fixed but not yet shipped to latest chrome lighthouse. I have commented on the issue asking the same to them. Please refer: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11154#issuecomment-688878126

Comment: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11154#issuecomment-688920613 - 
Yes, it should be fixed in Chrome Canary and is part of Chrome 86 (becomes stable in October).

Answer (score 2):

Could be a variety of factors. Post the URL along with the question - easier to debug.

1. Speed index - has a blocker, if anything takes more than 10secs, LightHouse will time-out.
2. If you are using CDN - I have experience sporadic errors on LightSpeed due to cache consistency issues.
3. Make sure there are no blockers on your site, and you run this on a new/private window. No browser extensions should be enabled.
4. LightHouse uses the same underlying API. Try using PSI - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/. Also, try the web version of lightspeed: https://web.dev/measure/. If you get same results - something on your end. If you get different results, something with your browser/ test.
5. Try running LightHouse on Mobile and Desktop.

Comment: mine gives me a good result in the mobile site but not in the desktop